# Decimal precision exceeds max precision despite decimal having the correct size and precision

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this code

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName("pyspark-sandbox")
    .getOrCreate()
)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType", "TIMESTAMP_MICROS")  # type: ignore

faker = Faker()
value = faker.pydecimal(left_digits=28, right_digits=10)
print(value) # 8824750032877062776842530687.8719544506

df = spark.createDataFrame([[value]], schema=['DecimalItem'])
df = df.withColumn('DecimalItem', col('DecimalItem').cast(DecimalType(38, 10)))
df.show()
```

But on `show` I get this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkArithmeticException: [DECIMAL_PRECISION_EXCEEDS_MAX_PRECISION] Decimal precision 46 exceeds max precision 38.
```

The value `8824750032877062776842530687.8719544506` seems to fit into `DecimalType`, yet it fails. What is the problem?

Comment: Try `DecimalType(28, 10)`. You've specified 38 integer digits *plus* 10 fraction digits.

Comment: Same issue "Decimal precision 46 exceeds max precision 38". I am not sure where it gets 46 or 38.

Comment: the point is that it got 46, not 48. but don't be rude. Anyway, I found the issue

Comment: @lapots - if the issue is solved, please share the root cause and workaround(s) as self answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I found out that if you pass `StructType` schema, when creating a dataframe - it works properly without issues.

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName("pyspark-sandbox")
    .getOrCreate()
)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType", "TIMESTAMP_MICROS")  # type: ignore

faker = Faker()
value = faker.pydecimal(left_digits=28, right_digits=10)
print(value) # 8824750032877062776842530687.8719544506

df = spark.createDataFrame([[value]], schema=StructType([StructField('DecimalItem', DecimalType(38, 10), True)]))
df.show()
```

Not sure why there is an issue with `cast` though. I guess you can't cast to a different DecimalType if Pyspark came up with its own?

Because if I check the schema using `df.printSchema` in my original approach

```
DecimalItem: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

it went with `38,18` by default.